# How can i extract and compare elements from a nested list in python?

Tags: python

I will post only the format of my list.
I am trying to split this list:

```
list1 = [["first","22","25","35"],["second","22","25","35"]]
```

Into this

```
list2 = [[["first"],["22"],["25"],["35"]],[["second"],["22"],["25"],["35"]]]
```

so i can iterate in list2[x][y], or any better idea please to compare values between list1

```
for x in list:
    list2.append(x.split(","))
```

But it says that list does not have split() method.

Again it is a learning project so it does not need to give me the straight answer, i am just looking for hints and help how to do it.

Comment: you want to compare sub_array elements with each other, ie. list1[0] elements with list1[1] elements ? If yes, you should read about `zip`

Comment: You can do this easily with list comprehension

Comment: You have nested lists; `["first", "22", "25", "35"]` is not a string, so there is no need to split anything.  You can *already* iterate over that object to get each individual string value from that; `for string_value in list1[0]:` works already and gives you the individual string values. There is *no advantage* to turning this into `[["first"], ["22"], ["25"], ["35"]]`, you only added a layer of list objects with each a single element.

Comment: You said "to compare values between list1". Does that mean you want to test if  "first"=="second", "22"=="22", etc?

Comment: Why do you want to *extract values* to compare them? What's wrong with `assert list1[0] == list1[1]`?

Comment: first and second will be just as identifier, but the number values has to be compared.

Comment: So `assert list1[0][1:] == list1[1][1:]`

Comment: Do you just want to test if the number values are equal? If they aren't equal do you want to identify which one is greater? What should the output look like? A single value of True or False? Or should it be a list containing the results of comparing each pair?

Comment: Hey OP, can you mention the required output clearly? like for so and so input, the output must be like this.

Comment: @SheikArbaz i am asked to return the greatest number for a certain element in a certain position, thats why i am spliting in different elements different lists, but maybe there are easier ways.

Comment: So you need position of greatest number in a list? Update your question with the exact problem description as for now it's totally unclear what do you want your script to do

Comment: @Andersson For a certain position on the of the list that contains element "first" compared for the same position on the list that  contains element "second"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) in nested manner to do something like this perhaps:

```
list1 = [["first","22","25","35"],["second","22","25","35"]]

list2 = list(map(lambda l: list(map(lambda e: [e], l)), list1))

print(list2)                 

# [[['first'], ['22'], ['25'], ['35']], [['second'], ['22'], ['25'], ['35']]]
```

However, if your objective is to **just compare each elements** you can do something like this:

```
list1 = [["first","22","25","35"],["second","22","25","35"]]
for e in zip(*list1):    # will also work even if list1 has more than two lists
    print(len(set(e)) == 1)

# False
# True
# True
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `zip` both sublist together and compare them from there

```
l = [*zip(list1[0], list1[1])]
```

Can be done with *List comprehension*:

```
l = [(list1[0][idx], list1[1][idx]) for idx, item in enumerate(list1[1])]
```

> ```
> [('first', 'second'), ('22', '22'), ('25', '25'), ('35', '35')]
> ```

From here you could just compare each tuple elements by using `[i][0] and [i][1]`

Comment: This is not what is being asked. The OP is adding a layer of 1-element lists to each string value. There is no pairing up being done.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  `any better idea please to compare values between list` What other values would he want to be comparing, I doubt OP is looking to compare `first` to `22` , it would make sense he is trying to compare corresponding indexes from each sublsit

Comment: @vash_the_stampede that's correct, corresponding indexes.

Comment: @SachiTakamori Yes then by zipping the sublists you could now just compare index 0 and 1 of each tuple, this would be much simpler than navigating through a list of individual sublists, and comparing them

Comment: @vash_the_stampede cant use zipping for this project :/

Comment: @vash_the_stampede: yet there is zero info in the question itself about comparing. If the question requires this much guesswork, it needs to be edited or closed.

Comment: @SachiTakamori: so why not *include this information in your question*. If you wanted to compare values with corresponding indices, we could have gotten you this information much faster. See [How to merge lists into a list of tuples?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2407398)

Comment: @SachiTakamori we can form the *tuples* using *list comprehsion* updated to show, if you wanted to make them lists instead of tuples, just change the `()` to `[]` inside the comprehension

Comment: @MartijnPieters so do you undownvote me seeing as I interpreted Op question correctly and responded with that he was actually intending to receive

Comment: Please don't make assumptions about who voted which way. That I am commenting on a post does not mean I am also voting. My votes are my own and so are my criteria of how I use them, please don't ask me to use or not use them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i am trying to learn man, for advanced programmers things are much easier, but my scope probably is not the same as yours so i was trying to do one thing at a time, and at this moment i was wondering to nest them and maybe it is easier to compare, maybe it wont work.

Comment: @SachiTakamori: this has nothing to do with what level you are. This is about how clear your question is; questions here must be useful to other people that might come visit here in future, because that's the goal of Stack Overflow: to collect great questions and their answers so that anyone with the same question can find it and see those answers. See [ask] for more information on how to write better questions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you very much, i will try harder next time!